# C# Parse XML with repeated pattern of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Resources>
    <Category Cause="ONE">
        <Resource Component="AAA" Name="cBackgroundTextA" />
        <Resource Component="BBB" Name="cBackgroundTextB" />
        <Resource Component="CCC" Name="cBackgroundTextC" />
    </Category>
    <Category Cause="TWO">
        <Resource Component="DDD" Name="cBackgroundTextD" />
        <Resource Component="EEE" Name="cBackgroundTextE" />
        <Resource Component="FFF" Name="cBackgroundTextF" />
    </Category>
    <Category Cause="THREE">
        <Resource Component="GGG" Name="cBackgroundTextG" />
        <Resource Component="HHH" Name="cBackgroundTextH" />
        <Resource Component="III" Name="cBackgroundTextI" />
    </Category>
</Resources>
```

How can i get the following:

> ONE , AAA , cBackgroundTextA
>
> ONE , BBB , cBackgroundTextB
>
> ONE , CCC , cBackgroundTextC
>
> TWO , DDD , cBackgroundTextD
>
> TWO , EEE , cBackgroundTextE
>
> ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get the values by:

```
xmlDocument = new XDocument();
xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath, LoadOptions.None);

var categoryNodeList = XmlDocument.Descendants("Category");

    foreach (XElement categoryItem in categoryNodeList)
    {
        foreach (XElement resourceItem in categoryItem.Elements())
        {
            var XmlObject = new ResultDetail
            {
                Cause = categoryItem.Attribute("Cause").Value,
                Component = resourceItem.Attribute("Component").Value,
                Name = resourceItem.Attribute("Name").Value
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the line:

```
XElement root;

foreach(var folder in root.Children()) { //For each folder
    var folderType = folder.Attribute("type").Value;
    foreach(var file in folder.Children()) { //For each  file

        Console.WriteLine($"{folderType} AND {file}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All required information can be gathered using single LINQ query :

```
var query = from cat in XmlDocument.Descendants("Category");
            from res in cat.Elements()
            select new ResultDetail
                    {
                        Cause = cat.Attribute("Cause").Value,
                        Component = res.Attribute("Component").Value,
                        Name = res.Attribute("Name").Value
                    };
```